# How to write/update session data before a request end in Perl Catalyst MVC Framework

Tags: perl, session-state, catalyst

How can I write or update session data before a request ends in Perl MVC Catalyst Framework.
I am using `Session::State::Cookie` and `Session::Store::FastMap`

I need to ensure that the data is available **before** the long-running request completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me. 
To ensure the information is updated at the time it is set in the long running request, I do a `$c->finalize_session` just after updating some importante information related to the session:

```
$c->session->{important_info} = "new value";
$c->finalize_session;
```

I verified that the other requests are gathering the right value after that. 
I did not observed any side effects calling `$c->finalize_session` many times during a request just to ensure the session data to be updated, but I am not certained about this.

One of the informations that I am setting in this way is a counter to update a progress bar to feedback the user (because this task takes a long time). I do not know if it is the best way to do that, I will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some last-second processing just before a request is completed and the response sent to the client by overriding the handle_request method in your application's main module or a plugin.

```
sub handle_request {
    my ($c, @args) = @_;

    my $status = $c->next::method(@args);

    # Do some last minute processing before the request is completed.

    return $status;
}
```

I've overridden this method before to collect stats about a request or restart a worker process if it uses too much memory.  Let me know if this is helpful or if you have more questions about it.